# Evan's proof of global approximation by smooth function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

[image]

In the Evan's proof, he defined $\lambda$ and $\epsilon$ at the same time. I am wondering whether we could just define $\epsilon$. For $\epsilon$ small enough, the property should still hold.

Comment: No you can't define just $\epsilon$. $\lambda$ makes sure that your point is enough far away from the boundary, such that the $\epsilon$-ball is contained in this set.

Comment: I thought that we only need to shift up a tiny bit to make room for mollification and stay in the $U\cap B(x^0,r)$. We define that $x^\epsilon = x+\epsilon e_n$ will have enough room.

Comment: It depends on what your $\gamma$ looks like. Assume that your domain is 2-dimensional and that for example on the interval $[0,2]$ your boundary can be represented as $\gamma(x)=2x$, thus locally all points above $\gamma$ belong to your domain. Take now the boundary point $(1,2)$. There exists no $\epsilon>0$ such that an $\epsilon$-ball around $(1,2+\epsilon)$ lies above $\gamma$ as a whole.